# Телеграмм-бот должен отправлять сообщение другому пользователю

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Я пишу бота на aiogram, и я хочу сделать так, чтобы при команде send бот отправлял сообщение другому пользователю, username которого должен быть указан в коде вручную. Я пробовал разные способы, спрашивал chatGPT, но пока ничего не работает. Что делать?
Мой код:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import asyncio


TOKEN_API = "TOKEN"

bot = Bot(TOKEN_API)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler()
async def mess(message: types.Message):
    if message.text!='/start' and message.text!='send':
        await message.answer(text='Я тебя не понмаю. Пиши "/start" чтобы начать диалог')
    elif message.text=='send':
        bot.send_message(chat_id="username", text="тестовое сообщение")
    else:
        await message.answer(text="Hi!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Как вы понимаете, вместо username в кавычках указан ник пользователя, которому нужно отправить сообщение, а вместо TOKEN - токен моего бота.

Comment: `chat_id` - это ID чата с пользователем, а не его никнейм

Comment: @ZxNuClear видимо гпт так подсказал

Comment: @Amgarak а следующим потрясением будет то, что боты не могут инициировать диалог :)

Comment: Т. е. чтобы бот инициализировал диалог, нужно какое-то обязательное условие? Бывает же иногда что ты подписываешься на какой-то паблик, и тебе автоматически пишет бот

Comment: условие одно - диалог может начать только человек, но никак не бот